# OpenGL not displaying 2D lines

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, glut

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and trying to implement 2d lines using OpenGl but it isn't displaying anything.  i am using ubuntu compiler.  I have installed the library using **terminal**.

here is my code

```c
#include <GL/glut.h>
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2i(10,10);
    glVertex2i(100,100);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize (500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow ("points and lines");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

this is how i am compiling and running my program

```
 g++ jamshaid.cpp -o jamoo -lglut -lGLU -lGL
./jamoo
```

## Update 1

added init2D and tried other answer as well but not working. it even doesn't changing the title of the window.

## update 2

after updating the code from [this](https://alala666888.wordpress.com/2010/06/06/opengl2d-draw-points-and-lines/) site. i now have this code and it's working. can you please explain the reason why is that so. thanks

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

 void init2D(float r, float g, float b)
 {
 glClearColor(r,g,b,0.0);  
 glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
gluOrtho2D (0.0, 200.0, 0.0, 150.0);
}

void display(void)
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2i(10,10);
    glVertex2i(100,100);
 glEnd();
 glFlush();
 }

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
 {
 glutInit(&argc,argv);
 glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
 glutInitWindowSize (500, 500);
 glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
 glutCreateWindow ("points and lines");
 init2D(0.0,0.0,0.0);
 glutDisplayFunc(display);
 glutMainLoop();
 return 0;}
```

Comment: Why are you running GCC as root?  Where's the code for `init2D()`?

Comment: @genpfault it's in display function. isn't it? in fact i am a beginer in opengl

Comment: if i don't root it. it results the same

Comment: I'm not seeing `init2D()` defined anywhere, just called in `main()`.

Comment: it  even works without that.

Comment: i am not sure what to do and not finding anything helpful on google as well

Comment: @Nancy If it still doesn't work, then try to use double buffering. `GLUT_DOUBLE` instead of `GLUT_SINGLE` and `glutSwapBuffers()` instead of `glFlush()`.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the exemple [here](https://alala666888.wordpress.com/2010/06/06/opengl2d-draw-points-and-lines/), you need a correct init2D function to initialize the 3D projection matrix before drawing.

```
void init2D(float r, float g, float b)
{
    glClearColor(r,g,b,0.0);  
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D (0.0, 200.0, 0.0, 150.0);
}
```

Comment: please have a look at the question

Comment: @TungLeThanh Please have a look at the answer ... because it tells you that you don't have a valid viewport ... I think the default is 1 by 1 ... and you start drawing at position 10. Increasing the pixels just stretches the 1-by-1 viewport.

Comment: can you please take a look at the question again and explain what you suggested?

Comment: Since the window size is (500, 500), I suggest to set an orthographic projection in the same range. So the world coordinates would be projected 1:1 to the window coordinates: [`gluOrtho2D (0.0, 500.0, 0.0, 500.0)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluOrtho2D.xml)

Answer (score 0):

As Tung Le Thanh told you, you need a correct projection matrix initialization, and this is what it does:

`glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION)`

> glMatrixMode — specify which matrix is the current matrix
>
> ```
>                 GL_PROJECTION
>                     Applies subsequent matrix operations to the projection matrix stack.
>                 GL_TEXTURE
>                     Applies subsequent matrix operations to the texture matrix stack.
>                 GL_COLOR
>                     Applies subsequent matrix operations to the color matrix stack.
>                 
>         To find out which matrix stack is currently the target of all matrix
>         operations, call glGet with argument GL_MATRIX_MODE. The initial
>         value is GL_MODELVIEW.
> ```

`gluOrtho2D`

> gluOrtho2D — define a 2D orthographic projection matrix
>
> Specification
>
> ```
> void gluOrtho2D(GLdouble left,  GLdouble right,  GLdouble bottom,  GLdouble top);
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> ```
>   left, right
>             Specify the coordinates for the left and right vertical clipping planes.
>   bottom, top
>             Specify the coordinates for the bottom and top horizontal clipping planes.
> ```
>
> Description
>
> ```
>         gluOrtho2D sets up a two-dimensional orthographic viewing region.
> ```